# Problems when trying to get datasnapshot into the class i want

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the data sent from my android app that is formed like this.[image]

I'm trying to do it on JavaScript. I originally did this on Java and it was something like this

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Chat chat = postSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
```

I want to do the same thing on JavaScript but failed when I'm trying to. What I have now is this

```
class Chat{
  constructor(detail,file_name,is_phone,type,user_id){
    this.detail = detail;
    this.file_name = file_name;
    this.is_phone = is_phone;
    this.type = type;
    this.user_id = user_id;
  }
  detail(){ return this.detail;}
  file_name(){ return this.file_name;}
  is_phone(){ return this.is_phone;}
  type(){ return this.type;}
  user_id(){ return this.user_id;}
}

//Sync obj changes
dbRefObj.on('child_added',snap => {
  myChat = new Chat (snap.val());
  console.log(myChat);
  });
```

But what I got is everything being set to detail...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that you want to spread the values, instead you're just assigning to the first parameter:

In the current implementation `snap.val()` is assigned to the detail param

```js
class Chat{
  constructor(detail, file_name, is_phone, type, user_id){
      // ...
  }
}
```

The following implementation will take the corresponding values from inside the `snap.val()`

```js
class Chat{
  constructor({ detail, file_name, is_phone, type, user_id}) {
      // The difference is the use of the deconstructive syntax
  }
}
```

Comment: class Chat{
  constructor({detail, file_name, is_phone, type, user_id}){
  }
  detail(){ return this.detail;}
  file_name(){ return this.file_name;}
  is_phone(){ return this.is_phone;}
  type(){ return this.type;}
  user_id(){ return this.user_id;}
}

I've made my class like this but not the myChat is returning nothing

Comment: Checkout this [working example here](https://repl.it/@ayushyamitabh/PartialSeveralExperiments#index.js) . I think you might not be defining your `myChat` variable properly? Try logging the `snap.val()` value and make sure it's a proper object.

Comment: My myChat is defined bymyChat = new Chat (snap.val()); which is from the database. I don't know if I'm doing it right

Comment: `var myChat = new Chat(snap.val())` please make sure to [review Javascript Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)

Comment: I figured out my problem and it was a dumb one. But thank you for your help in providing the solution for the constructor! I solved it now

Comment: No worries, please make sure to accept my answer if it worked for you